# multipart form validate with validate.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use a multipage form with validate.js, however the fields aren't validating doing it this way. What I'm actually doing is using JQuery to hide and show the form fields to get to multiple pages. However, I am using one JQuery file to do this, and of course another to validate the forms. Would this cause a problem?

The jsfiddle is below. The JSFiddle doesn't actualy work becuse there are 2 JQuery files, but just wanted you to see the html and javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/tunm34p1/1/

```
$("#mbContact").validate({

        rules:{
            fname:{
                required:true
            },
            lname:{
                required: true
            },
            csheme:{
                required: true
            },
            deladdr:{},
            emailaddress:{
                email: true,
                required: true
            },
            typeOfEvent:{
                required: true
            },
            homePhone:{
                digits: true
            },
            workPhone:{
                digits: true
            },
            mobilePhone:{
                digits: true
            }
        },
        messages:{
            fname:{
                required:"You need to enter your name!"
            },
            lname:{
                required:"you need your last name too!"
            }
    }
});
```

Another JQuery document here

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("button, input[type='button']").click(function(){
            $('#contact').hide();
            $('#nextForm').show();
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

- by default the validator does not validate hidden elements - this can be controlled via the `ignore` option
- You need to change the default error display mechanism

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#mbContact").validate({
    ignore: '',
    //if page wise validation is not enabled
    errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
    wrapper: "li",

    rules: {
      fname: {
        required: true
      },
      lname: {
        required: true
      },
      csheme: {
        required: true
      },
      deladdr: {},
      emailaddress: {
        email: true,
        required: true
      },
      typeOfEvent: {
        required: true
      },
      homePhone: {
        digits: true
      },
      workPhone: {
        digits: true
      },
      mobilePhone: {
        digits: true
      }

    },

    messages: {

      fname: {
        required: "You need to enter your name!"
      },
      lname: {
        required: "you need your last name too!"
      }



    }

  });



});


//another jquery document

$(document).ready(function() {


  $("button, input[type='button']").click(function() {
    //move to next page only of current one is valid
    if(!$('#contact').find(':input').valid()){
      return;
    }
    
    $('#contact').hide();
    $('#nextForm').show();
  });


});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<h2>Contact Form</h2>
<!-- if page wise validation is not enabled -->
<ul id="messageBox"></ul>
<div id="contact" class="basic-grey" style="">
  <form id="mbContact" action="" method="post">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" />
    <br/>
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" />
    <br/>
    <label for="emailaddress">Email Address</label>
    <input id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" type="text" />
    <br/>
    <label for="typeOfEvent">Type Of Event</label>
    <select name="typeOfEvent" id="typeOfEvent">
      <option value>Select</option>
      <option value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
      <option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
      <option value="Special Occasion">Special Occasion</option>
      <option value="BabyShower">Baby Shower</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <label for="datepicker">Event Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
    <br/>
    <label for="cscheme">Color Scheme</label>
    <input id="cscheme" name="cscheme" type="text" />
    <br/>
    <label for="noOfServings">Number Of Servings</label>
    <select name="noOfServings" id="noOfServings">
      <option value>Choose Number</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="next" name="next" class="nextB" />
</div>
<div id="nextForm" style="display:none;" class="basic-grey">
  <label for="noOfTiers">Number Of Tiers</label>
  <select name="noOfTiers" id="noOfTiers">
    <option value>Tiers</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <label for="workPhone">Work Telephone</label>
  <input type="text" id="workPhone" name="workPhone" />
  <br/>
  <label for="homePhone">Home Telephone</label>
  <input type="text" id="homePhone" name="homePhone" />
  <br/>
  <label for="mobilePhone">Mobile Telephone</label>
  <input type="text" id="mobilePhone" name="mobilePhone" />
  <br/>
  <label for="deladdr">Delivery Address</label>
  <input id="deladdr" name="deladdr" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" name="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

Note: You will have to add a previous button so that use can go back to previous page to fix the errors.

Comment: so if they click 'next' for the next form and there is something invalid, is there a way for that to not allow the next page to show?

Comment: i did it, and i understand what you did (thank you btw), but i like the errors to be displayed in the place they were. I was just wondering if there was a way for validation to take place upon clicking 'next' rather than only when clicking submit

Comment: @user2461224 check it now... the validation on `next` click is working now